# How to unbind a gpu /sys/bus/pci

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, libvirt, gpu-passthrough

How do I unbind an Nvidia GPU in `/sys/bus/pci/driver/nvidia/unbind` in order to use it for virtualization

I am using `sudo echo "0000:09:00.0" > unbind` but I get `bash: unbind: Permission denied`

I am following the docs from [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/linux-on-systems?topic=through-pci),but can't seem to figure out to unbind the gpu

the os I am using is `ubuntu 22.04`

when running the command `echo "0000:09:00.0" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/unbind` this cause the terminal to hang and I can't use it anymore

even trying to kill the process fails

```
root        8646  0.0  0.0  14356  5912 pts/0    S+   09:07   0:00 sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/unbind
root        8647  0.0  0.0  14356   956 pts/1    Ss+  09:07   0:00 sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/unbind
root        8648 11.5  0.0   8380  1024 pts/1    R    09:07   0:14 tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/unbind
```

Comment: You want `echo "0000:09:00.0" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/driver/nvidia/unbind` instead.

Comment: @telcoM this never returns to the terminal and i have to either kill the terminal or restart the machine

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to unbind the GPU that is currently being used to display the terminal window? Does `dmesg` output indicate anything about the unbind operation? Also, have you already configured the X11 or Wayland display server to leave the Nvidia GPU alone so that it is free to be used by virtualization? It might be best to switch to text console mode (e.g. `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`) to unbind the GPU and assign it to `vfio_pci`, so the graphics subsystem will not get confused by the GPU unbinding, then return to GUI: `systemctl isolate graphical.target`.

Comment: The document from IBM you linked is clearly intended for server use (= perhaps no local GUI at all, only remote), and seems to have an unstated assumption that the PCI device that is being unbound is not currently configured for use in the host OS when unbinding it. Because the modern GUI subsystems (both Xorg X11 and Wayland) attempt to auto-detect all GPU devices by default, that assumption is not necessarily true by default on GPU devices: the GUI subsystem may have auto-configured the Nvidia GPU, just to see if it has any displays connected to it.